# Now...where was I?

Tags: word, wordplay, geography, homonym

Below are some observations and random thoughts from a recent trip:

> A barrel maker passing on some oolong.
>
> Brimming with an unspecified amount.
>
> An unpretentious piggy.
>
> Astonished by an unobserved restoration.
>
> Fifteen à la mode.
>
> A digit ritually imparting divine grace.

**Where could I have seen all of this?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Clearly you were visiting

> California.

```
A barrel maker passing on some oolong.
```

> **Cupertino** (cooper, tea? no)

```
Brimming with an unspecified amount.
```

> **Folsom** (full some)

```
An unpretentious piggy.
```

> **Modesto** (modest toe) -- thanks to GPR in comments and Matthew Barber in his own answer for spotting the toe.

```
Astonished by an unobserved restoration.
```

> Maybe **Mendocino** (mend + o-cin = zero + ~seen = unseen + O!)? I can't say I find "-ocin-"="unobserved" very convincing, though.

```
Fifteen à la mode.
```

> **Chico** (chic O; O is the 15th letter of the alphabet)

```
A digit ritually imparting divine grace.
```

> **Sacramento** (sacrament 0)

Comment: Very nicely done so far! I will tell you that one of your bold answers is correct. And the other in question will be one word, so no "Hidden X" ;)

Comment: Well, if one of the bold ones is right then my best guess is that it's the "fifteen" one, but the best attempt I can find at a complete explanation is, I think, just plain wrong. But I'll edit it into my answer anyway :-).

Comment: For the unpretentious piggy, consider the nursery rhyme, "This little piggy went to market".  And note that two **T**s combine into one to give you the answer.  (Trying not to put spoilers in the comment.)

Comment: This clearly has to be right (and means, to my relief, that my _other_ proposed answer that I didn't really believe was in fact wrong). I have to admit that for me it's quite a long way from being homonymous...

Comment: Good luck Solvang this one.

Comment: 15 could refer to the date on which Caesar was killed.

Comment: That's an extremely ingenious suggestion. I think it would have to be "fifteenth" then, though, and a quick look through some lists doesn't turn up anything obvious that fits. (But I could easily have missed something.)

Comment: You got it! For the rot13(Mraqbpvab) answer, my thinking was rot13(Zraq-BU!-Frr-ab). Nice work! Check mark, well earned.

Answer (score 5):

A barrel maker passing on some oolong.

> Cooper tea no -> Cupertino

Brimming with an unspecified amount.

> Full a ton -> Fullerton

An unpretentious piggy

> Modest sow -> Modesto (this is probably not right). Looking like California

Answer (score 4):

An unpretentious piggy:

> Modesto - with modest meaning unpretentious and piggy as in toe.

Credit to Dr Xorile and Gareth McCaughan for both getting all but that last part of it.

Answer (score 2):

Partial

Following on form the pattern established by Dr Xorile and Gareth McCaughan

Astonished by an unobserved restoration.
is

> Encino (unseen awe)

Comment: This is a good guess, but I decided not to include neighborhoods in this puzzle. Just proper cities.